# @SpringBootTest: pre-test logging set to debug by default?

Tags: spring-boot, logging

A bare-bones spring-boot project ([Initializr link](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.5.2.RELEASE&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo)) generates a `@SpringBootTest` class that spits the following `DEBUG` logging messages:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - ...
DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - ... 
DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - ... 
DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - ...
DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - ...
DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - ...
DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener - ...
DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils - ...
```

This happens before the actual test class begins executing.

1. Where is the config that enables that logging?
2. Where is this functionality documented?
3. How to turn it off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the information [@simon-martinelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1045142/simon-martinelli) provided, this [Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing-log-level) could also be helpful.

In summary: you could add a logback-test.xml to the root of the test classpath to configure the loglevels to avoid DEBUG logs or to completely disable the logging. :)

Answer (score 2):

Both [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1045142/simon-martinelli) and [Ingo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3663953/ingo-griebsch) mentioned configuring logback, which turned-out to be the correct method to disable the debug messages (initially, I misplaced the logback conf file, which was why I commented earlier that it didn't work. Apologies).

`src/test/resources/logback.groovy`:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder

appender('STDOUT', ConsoleAppender) {
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = '%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n'
    }
}
logger 'org.springframework.test', WARN
root(INFO, ["STDOUT'])
```

To clarify:

the config that enables debug is *not* spring boot's, but rather the [logback default](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html):

> Assuming the configuration files logback-test.xml or logback.xml are not present, logback will default to invoking BasicConfigurator... Moreover, by default the root logger is assigned the DEBUG level.

Loggers in `org.springframework.test` (e.g `BootstrapUtils`) are statically-initialized, so by the time the application context is loaded and reads `application.properties`, those loggers will have already been built, inheriting their level from `ROOT`, which is by-default `debug`.

Comment: earlier you commented on Simons answer that spring boot logging does not work to disable these messages. isn't that still correct? as per this answer, spring boot logging config can't be used to silence these messages, but logback configuration needs to be used.

Comment: That's correct. The logging messages I posted cannot be controlled through application.properties, because they're being logged before spring boot even initializes its context.